# PyGTK and visual-python

Tags: python, pygtk, python-multithreading, vpython

I'm developing an application with PyGTK that will make use of visual-python's 3d drawings and animations, but I can't get both libraries to work together: they either hung up when I close the Gtk window or they get stuck when I run the application.

I've tried with threads and they run side-by-side, but when I close visual-python's window this kills python's interpreter, raising a Segmentation Fault.

Has anyone been able to use visual-python from a PyGtk app?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10934787/232794) for a partial answer.  Sadly, see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11265110/232794) for a bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-trivial problem given the way that VPython wants to work, but there is an [example](http://mientki.ruhosting.nl/data_www/pylab_works/pw_vpython_docking.html) in the [contributed programs](http://vpython.org/contents/contributed.html) section of the VPython web site that shows how to embed VPython into a wxPython application, so perhaps you can look over that code and determine what you would need to do to perform the same magic in PyGTK.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a look. I've never worked with wxPython but it should be pretty straightforward to port the idea behind the code.